# Apply the default ListView item onTouch animation to a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-animation

Pretty much what the title says.

When you touch down on an item in a ListView you get a nice animation. I would like to play this animation when I touch a LinearLayout.

I imagine the code would be similar to:

```
final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ll);
ll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Animation animation = null; // = ?

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ll.startAnimation(animation);
        } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            ll.getAnimation().cancel();
            ll.getAnimation().reset();
        } 

        return true;
    }
});
```